# HttpURLConnection 403 response after 200

Tags: java, android, https

Ok so I'm working on an app with 2 activities.

Let's call the 1st one LoginActivity which appears on top of my MainActivity. Also, I have a class SenderReceiver which extends AsyncTask that takes care of the connection to my https server.

The 1st time I call SenderReceiver from my LoginActivity, everything works fine & I get a 200 response & I'm able to use the JSON retrieved.
After that, the LoginActivity finishes & returns a result to the MainActivity. This is when I know I'm logged in & I can proceed.

Now whenever I execute SenderReceiver to get other information, I get the 403 response with a java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://url_of_my_server. But if I call the login again, it works.

Below is the SenderReceiver code snippet which connects to the server.

I'm also connecting to the same server on the iOS version of the app & never have issues with subsequent calls after the login.

Now this is my 1st time using https connections & such, I'm not really sure how it works on Android so I must be missing something or doing something wrong.

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
    frag = (Fragment)params[0]; // For later
    addedParams = (List<NameValuePair>)params[1];
    postPage = (String)params[2];

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(Constants.kWebService);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        //conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("CONTENT_TYPE", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");

        String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((Constants.kHTTPSUser+":"+Constants.kHTTPSPass).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);

        String param = "page="+postPage+"&";
        for(int i = 0; i < addedParams.size(); i++) {
            String and = (i < addedParams.size()-1)? "&": "";
            param += addedParams.get(i).getName()+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(addedParams.get(i).getValue(), "UTF-8")+and;
        }
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(param);
        out.close();

        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        responseSTR = Constants.inputStreamToString(is).toString();
        return true;
        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } catch (ProtocolException pe) {
        Constants.Log("Protocol Exception:"+pe.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException io) {
        Constants.Log("IO Exception:"+io.getMessage());
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException io) {
                Constants.Log("is.close IO Exception:"+io.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use Postman or advance rest client in your browser to check whether your api call is working or not

Comment: Hi Clairvoyant, thanks for the suggestion, I'm already using Postman, everything is working fine, that's why I thought there may be something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

All I had to do was to set the cookie header with:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Constants.kCookies);
```

& retrieve that cookie after the response in order to set it with:

```
List<String> cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
if(cookies != null) {
    Constants.kCookies = cookies.get(0);
}
```

That way in the initial HttpURLConnection connections (i.e:login) the cookie is empty & not needed. Once a connection is successful (after "login") it receives the cookie & sets it.

After that, any subsequent connection sends that cookie as part of the header.

The updated method below:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
    frag = (Fragment)params[0];
    addedParams = (List<NameValuePair>)params[1];
    postPage = (String)params[2];

    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(Constants.kWebService);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        //conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.setRequestProperty("CONTENT_TYPE", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");

        String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((Constants.kHTTPSUser+":"+Constants.kHTTPSPass).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);

        // Get the cookie from my Constants file & set it, Constants.kCookies is a static String
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", Constants.kCookies);

        String param = "page="+postPage+"&";
        for(int i = 0; i < addedParams.size(); i++) {
            String and = (i < addedParams.size()-1)? "&": "";
            param += addedParams.get(i).getName()+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(addedParams.get(i).getValue(), "UTF-8")+and;
        }
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(param);
        out.close();

        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Constants.Log("The response code is: " + responseCode);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Retrieve the cookie from the response & if not null save it to Constants.kCookies
        List<String> cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
        if(cookies != null) {
            Constants.kCookies = cookies.get(0);
        }

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        responseSTR = Constants.inputStreamToString(is).toString();//readIt(is, len);
        return true;
        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } catch (ProtocolException pe) {
        Constants.Log("Protocol Exception:"+pe.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException io) {
        Constants.Log("IO Exception:"+io.getMessage());
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException io) {
                Constants.Log("is.close IO Exception:"+io.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```